# Can I layer an image on top of pointer image

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm currently working on an interactive infographic about winter sports. I've replaced the mouse pointer with a little skiër. And depending on the mouse position the image changes to him making a different turn.

So this is al working well, but I would also like to add a cable car layered on top of the mouse pointer. So on screen this would look like he's skiing underneeth the cable car.

So in essence I want an image layered on top of the mouse cursor visually.

I've tried googling but I have had no luck. So I'm posting here.

If you need any elaboration feel free to ask, I can sent the code aswell.

Thanks in advance!

Pieter

Edit:
So this is the code I use for this part of the infographic:

```
<html>
        <div id="skierlinks"></div>
        <div id="skierrechts"></div>
        <div id="skiermidden"></div>
    </html>

Css: 
#skierlinks {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 850px;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 33%;
  align-items: left;
  cursor: url(../images/skierlinks.png), pointer;
  background-color: snow;
}
#skiermidden {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 850px;
  left: 33%;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 33%;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: url(../images/skier.png), pointer;
  background-color: snow;
}
#skierrechts {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 850px;
  left: 66%;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 33%;
  align-items: right;
  cursor: url(../images/skierrechts.png), pointer;
  background-color: snow;
}
```

As you can see when the mouse is on a different place of the screen it will change to a different image. But I would like an extra image to be on top of it.

https://mega.nz/file/oZtFjC7D#-f6ae1KeeE6cc5kk-hcRB0r0a4W9ASP6mbddOQpfe30

If you want to see how this would look.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Positioning based on the cursor is possible, you would probably need to hide the cursor to give the illusion of overlap though.

Comment: You can get an element (your cable car) to move with the cursor by listening for mouseup/down/move events in Javascript, reading the cursor coordinates and changing the position of the element to a few px above the cursor position. See for example [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event